# When will I use this kind of function declaration?

Tags: javascript, function

I saw this kind of function declaration many times when reading other peoples's code.

```
var foo = function bar() {
    console.log("Some text");
};
```

And I got this result.

```
foo();    // "Some text"
bar();    // Uncaught ReferenceError: bar is not defined(…)
```

Since `bar` stays undefined, I wonder what the purpose of writing `bar` there and the difference if I write it with omitting `bar`. However, I wonder if there is a certain condition or a reason why people write function like that.

When will I write function like that?

Comment: if the function throws an error, the stack trace will show that it happened in function bar rather than anonymous

Answer (score 1):

When you write `var foo = function() {}` you declare a variable named `foo` that has an anonymous function (function that has no name).

When you write `var foo = function bar() {}` you declare a variable named `foo` that has a function named `bar`.  This is useful for debugging. When you have an error, it will show that it's in `function bar()`.

Since function names are only available inside the function, calling `bar()` throws an error.